# Getting a height of a table which is inside a div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div inside which there is a table which doesn't have an id or CSS class to select. How can i get the height of this table.[image: div with table]

I want to set the height of the div[ class="t-grid-content"] to the table height which is inside it. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
var hieght =$('div.t-grid-content').height();
$('div.t-grid-content > table').height(height);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful.

```
$('div.t-grid-content table').height($('div.t-grid-content').height())
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MebBy/)**

Try this..

```
$('.t-grid-content>table:first-child').height($('.t-grid-content').height());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS

```
.t-grid-content  > table{
    height: 100%;
}
```